# Copy User Subfolders Using Robocopy

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I am trying to copy the `Normal.dotm` from all user's `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` to `C:\Temp\%username%`. I'm specifically trying to backup the data before a reinstall as part of an SCCM Task Sequence. Any thoughts?

I have tried a few different scripts using robocopy and it either gets stuck in a loop or only copies one directory.

```
robocopy C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\. C:\Temp\%username% /s /create
```

Only copies directory cmd is run as:

```
robocopy C:\Users\ C:\Temp\ /s /xjd normal.dotm
```

Creates loop and creates `C:\Users\Application\Data\Application Data\` forever

Answer (score 1):

The account running this will need to be an Administrator in order to access everyone's directories. When you believe the correct commands are being created, remove the lower case `echo` from them.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B "C:\Users\Normal.dotm"') DO (
    SET "TDIR=C:\temp%%~pf"
    IF NOT EXIST "%TDIR%" (echo MKDIR "%TDIR%")
    echo COPY "%%~f" "%TDIR%"
)
```

Comment: I just thought that the user wanted to copy just the `Normal.dotm` file to `C:\Temp\username`, not the whole structure.

Comment: There is no guarantee that there is only one (1) `Normal.dotm` file. Only the `Normal.dotm` file will be copied into the directory structure. The subdirectory structure does not require significant storage space.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a different way:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R "C:\Users\" %%A IN (Normal.dotm) do (
    set "fpath=%%~fA"
    if not "!fpath:\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\=!" == "!fpath!" (

        rem Find username:
        for /F "tokens=3 delims=\" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
            set "current_username=%%B"
        )

        rem Copy files:
        copy "!fpath!" "C:\Temp\!current_username!\"
    )
)
```

That, of course, requires administrator privileges, you cannot enter other users directories without admin privileges. Right-click on your file and select 'Run As Administrator'.